# Is this an appropriate roof setup

Tags: framing, roof, structural, timber-framing

I am creating a standard A frame roof (4.5:12 or 5:12 pitch) for my shed using rafters and a ridge board. The ridge board is 2x8 and is spanning 14 feet for the length of the shed (12x14). I am using 2x6s for the rafters 16 inches on center and connecting to the ridge board using the following:

[Rafter hanger](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-RR-Ridge-Rafter-Connector/1203733?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_213_Decorative-Hardware-_-1203733-_-0-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gbraid=0AAAAAD2B2W_QDcrfaBVvADY2cHhuRgu33&gclid=CjwKCAiAs92MBhAXEiwAXTi255v2j4bRJmxZ9U8xWbJ8XbVFDpoQKjXi4jFAUOivWkSgXWYXp9mbYhoCvLkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

And the bottom of the rafter attaches to the top plate of the supporting walls using this [rafter tie connector]
(https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-H2-5AZ-Hurricane-Tie-Z-Max/1005125). Then on the other side of each rafter I was going to run a 2x6 rafter tie joist across the 12ft width and nail that too the rafters and again connect that rafter tie to the top plate as well with the hurricane rafter tie connectors noted above. I was thinking this would create a extremely strong connection to stop all force on the outside walls. I wanted a loft on each side of the shed using the rafter ties as floor joists but keep the center section of the shed ceiling open to easily access them so can I skip the center rafter ties? My concern is these rafter ties would then be unsupported from exerting out word pressure on the supporting walls. I was hopping that if all the other rafter tie joists are connected to the top plate then this adds some strength to keep the walls from spreading for the rafters that are not supported by rafter ties..

I will have 6 inch overhangs and roof rake ladders connected via fascia board and ridge board on the gable ends.

The next part of the roof is where I get iffy. The ridge board should be self supported by the rafters but to get the rafter board in place to setup the rafters I was going to create support on the side wall top plate to hold the ridge board. I was thinking of leaving this in place to provide additional support. However doing this kind of turns my ridge board into a ridge beam in a way and I was curious if that could cause issues later on that I am not seeing (ie my side walls are just 2x4 16 inches on center ).

Comment: A picture/drawing/sketch would be helpful for clarity. A ridge board is entirely optional. You appear to be describing a straightforward triangle bracing where the joists are tying the rafters at each end, but not in the middle, correct? Please [edit] to disambiguate that you appear to refer to your joists as both rafters and "rafter ties" - if it's at the bottom of the attic space resting on the top plate of the walls, it's a joist, and without a sketch it's clearer if you always call it that, while the rafters are the bits with a roof attached to them.

Comment: Yes I was talking about a triangle bracing setup. From my understanding a rafter tie is a joist and it is the lower part of the triangle bracing and connects to the rafter and rests on the top plate. However from everything I have read online it is unclear if the rafter tie should also directly be nailed to the top plate as well. I plan to use the rafter tie (joist) as a floor to my loft. I will have a loft on each gable end but was planning to not do any rafter ties(joists) in the center of the shed so I can access each loft.